# User input for name and two validations

Tags: python

Need to enter user name, name must be between 5 and 10 characters long. Also must be only alpha characters.
If entered correct will print "User name accepted"
if incorrect will print "user name invalid"

I've wrote the code and some reason it will only validate one filed but not both. I've switched and re-wrote code about 5 times over. Think it's something very small I'm missing but can not find it.
I'd appreciate any help.  Here's the code.

---

```
name = str(input("Enter a username that has only alphabetical 
characters and is between 5 and 10 characters:"))
if len(name) < 5 or len(name) > 10:
  elif name.isalpha()==True:
  print("Invalid username! Please try again.")
  else:
  print("user name accepted")
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't mean `elif` when you check `name.isalpha()` but rather another `if` statement, like this:

```
name = str(input("Enter a username that has only alphabetical 
characters and is between 5 and 10 characters:"))
if len(name) < 5 or len(name) > 10:
  if name.isalpha():
    print("user name accepted")
  else:
    print("Invalid username! Please try again.")
```

Comment: Yeah, my son is laughing at me. I was under the impression if you use "if" statement you cant use another. You'd have to use an "elif" statements in middle and an "else" statement as the end. Knowing this now, makes things much easier for me. Thanks so much for the help.